# How can i get the Date of birth date from age number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
--My Age format will be like '056Yrs03Mths13Days/Male'

DECLARE @INPUT VARCHAR(250),@DATE_OF_BIRTH DATETIME,
@YEARS BIGINT , @MONTHS  BIGINT ,@DAYS BIGINT 


set @INPUT='056Yrs03Mths13Days/Male' --My INPUT age format will be like this.

SET @YEARS=CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING(@AGE_NME,1,3))
--select @YEARS

SET @MONTHS=CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING(@AGE_NME,CHARINDEX ('M',@AGE_NME,1)-2,2))
--SELECT @MONTHS

SET @DAYS=CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING(@AGE_NME,CHARINDEX ('D',@AGE_NME,1)-2,2))
--SELECT @DAYS


SET @DATE_OF_BIRTH= ?
```

Comment: i want the exact Date for the above input params.please help me out

Comment: why did you tag it as MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
SET @DATE_OF_BIRTH=DATEADD(year, -@Years, 
                           DATEADD(month, -@Months, 
                           DATEADD(day, -@Days, getDate())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two `DATEADD`s would be enough:

```
DECLARE @DATE_OF_BIRTH date 
    = DATEADD(year, -@Years, DATEADD(month, -@Months, GETDATE()))-@days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @YEARS=CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING( @INPUT,1,3))

SET @MONTHS=CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING( @INPUT,CHARINDEX ('M', @INPUT,1)-2,2))

SET @DAYS=CONVERT(BIGINT,SUBSTRING( @INPUT,CHARINDEX ('D', @INPUT,1)-2,2))

SET @DATE_OF_BIRTH=DATEADD(year, -@Years,
DATEADD(month, -@Months,DATEADD(day, -@Days, getDate())))
SELECT Convert(nvarchar(12),@DATE_OF_BIRTH,105)
```